# Bxslider carousel with bootstrap align to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bxslider

I have a bootstrap page that I have a bxslider Carousel (http://bxslider.com/) on and I would like it to align to the left the code is simply:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
```

[image]

```
</div>
```

Now I have tried the below and it didn't change:

To see the page the URL is:  http://allthings.trade/farming/Details/Silver-wyandotte-chickens/35523cea-a502-46e4-9211-10fcecae664e

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try bx-wrapper to float left and hopefully your issue is fixed..

```html
.bx-wrapper{ float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Floats**

You can float an element to the left or right with class pull-left or pull-right respectively.the following example demonstrates this.

```
<div class="pull-left">
   Quick Float to left
</div>

<div class="pull-right">
   Quick Float to right
</div>
```

You can also use **text-right** or **text-left** helper classes for the same.

[image: text-right or text-left]

Hope it solved your issue.